# VBA Transfer information from sheets in workbook 1, to sheets with same sheetname in another workbook

Tags: vba

I want to transfer information to a target workbook from a source workbook when the target sheet name is the source sheet name.

I am realtively new to VBA, have been working with it for 2 weeks now and have literally googled my a$$ off. This website has proven to be the best hulp so far.

I have to transpose much information on a standard basis to a different format, where I want to fI want to automate this by the following code:

```
Sub Transfer()
Dim wbt As Workbook, wbs As Workbook 'wbt = workbook target, wbs = workbooksource
Dim wst As Worksheet, wss As Worksheet 'wbt = worksheet target, wbs = worksheet source
Dim wkt As Integer, wks As Integer, wke As Integer 'wkt = number in target sheet name, wks = number in source sheet name, wke = number in sheet name after which I want to stop transferring information

Dim vFile As Variant

Dim CCT As Range, CCS As Range

Set wbt = ActiveWorkbook

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsm", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)


If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile

Set wbs = ActiveWorkbook

 wkt = 1
 wks = 1
 wke = 16

For Each wks In wbt.wst.("WK " & wkt)

       If wks = wkt Then

    wbt.wst("WK " & wkt).Range("K13:K63").Value = wbs.wss("WK " & wks).Range("G8:G58").Value
    wbt.wst("WK " & wkt).Range("m13:m63").Value = wbs.wss("WK " & wks).Range("h8:h58").Value

    wkt = wkt + 1
    wks = wks + 1

    If wke > wkt Then

        wbs.Close (False)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? do you get an error? If yes, on which line and which message?.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better already :

```
Sub Transfer()
Dim wbt As Workbook, wbs As Workbook 'wbt = workbook target, wbs = workbooksource
Dim wst As Worksheet, wss As Worksheet 'wbt = worksheet target, wbs = worksheet source
Dim wkt As Integer, wks As Integer, wke As Integer 'wkt = number in target sheet name, wks = number in source sheet name, wke = number in sheet name after which I want to stop transferring information

Dim vFile As Variant

Dim CCT As Range, CCS As Range

Set wbt = ActiveWorkbook

vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsm", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)


If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub


Set wbs = Workbooks.Open(vFile)

' wkt = 1
' wks = 1
 wke = 16

For Each wss In wbs.Sheets
    For Each wst In wbt.Sheets

        If wst.Name <> wss.Name Or CInt(Replace(wss.Name, "WK ", "")) >= wke Then
        Else
            wst.Range("K13:K63").Value = wss.Range("G8:G58").Value
            'wbt.wst("WK " & wkt).Range("m13:m63").Value = wbs.wss("WK " & wks).Range("h8:h58").Value

'            wkt = wkt + 1
'            wks = wks + 1
        End If
'        If wke > wkt Then wbs.Close (False)
    Next wst
Next wss

wbs.Close
Set wbs = Nothing
Set wbt = Nothing
End Sub
```

I don't really get your "wke", it is a number in the sheetname on which you want to limit your copy? If it is, the code might be changed enough already.

Btw, the `Set` is kind of a way to create quicker references for later use in code but you can't add arguments in there and you have to free them at the end of your code, `Set ... =  Nothing`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reseponses. I have actually found a way to make the code rune fluently. The completed code is:
Option Explicit
Sub Data_Transfer_Ur1_1_1_to_UR1_2()

```
Dim wbt As Workbook, wbs As Workbook
Dim wst As Worksheet, wss As Worksheet

Dim vFile As Variant

Dim CCT As Range, CCS As Range
Dim array1(1 To 53) As String
Dim og As Integer, bg As Integer

'Set source workbook
Set wbt = ActiveWorkbook

'Open the target workbook
vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xlsm", _
    1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
'if the user didn't select a file, exit sub

If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open vFile
'Set targetworkbook

Dim j As Integer

DataTransferUserForm.Show

og = DataTransferUserForm.InputBoxOG.Value
bg = DataTransferUserForm.InputBoxBG.Value

For j = og To bg
    array1(j) = "WK " + CStr(j)
Next j
Set wbs = ActiveWorkbook

Dim i As Integer


For i = 1 To UBound(array1)


        wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("K13:K63").Value = wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("G8:G58").Value
        wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("m13:m63").Value = wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("h8:h58").Value

        Set CCT = wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("O13")

    For Each CCS In wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("J8:J58")

        If CCS.Value > 0 Then
            CCT.Value = "z"
            CCT.Offset(0, 1).Value = CCS.Value
        End If
        Set CCT = CCT.Offset(1, 0)
    Next

    Set CCT = wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("O13")
    For Each CCS In wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("K8:K58")
        If CCS.Value > 0 Then
           CCT.Value = "i"
           CCT.Offset(0, 1).Value = CCS.Value
        End If
        Set CCT = CCT.Offset(1, 0)
    Next

    Set CCT = wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("O13")
    For Each CCS In wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("L8:L58")
        If CCS.Value > 0 Then
            CCT.Value = "v"
            CCT.Offset(0, 1).Value = CCS.Value
        End If
        Set CCT = CCT.Offset(1, 0)
    Next

    Set CCT = wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("O13")
    For Each CCS In wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("m8:m58")
        If CCS.Value > 0 Then
            CCT.Value = "o"
            CCT.Offset(0, 1).Value = CCS.Value
        End If
        Set CCT = CCT.Offset(1, 0)
    Next

    Set CCT = wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("O13")
    For Each CCS In wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("n8:n58")
        If CCS.Value > 0 Then
        CCT.Value = "bv"
        CCT.Offset(0, 1).Value = CCS.Value
        End If
           Set CCT = CCT.Offset(1, 0)
    Next

        wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("q13:q63").Value = wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("O8:O58").Value
        wbt.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("r13:r63").Value = wbs.Worksheets(array1(i)).Range("P8:P58").Value

Next i

wbs.Close (False)
wbt.Show
```